# How to know if SwiftUI List is on Top or is Scrolled

Tags: list, foreach, swiftui, event-handling, scrollview

I need animate the addition of new objects to the List only when the List is on Top.

Something like this:

```
List(items) { item in
    ItemRow(item: item)
}
.animation(onTop ? .default : nil)
```

How can I know when a SwiftUI List is on Top or is scrolled?

Comment: When a `List` is on top of that? Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Yrb he means he wants to know if the List is scrolled all the way to the top or not.